# How to make a Microsoft Teams call using azure logic-app

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a requirement where I am using azure logic-app to create following flow.

1. Using azure logic-app, I have to create Microsoft Teams.
2. Add members to Microsoft Teams
3. Create a new Channel within newly created MS Teams.
4. Post a message into a channel.
5. It should call to all the members within the teams using "Meet Now" option in MS Team.

I am able to achieve all the above till 4th step but I am not getting any way to make a call to the members in MS team using "Meet Now" option in azure logic-app.

If anybody can suggest how to achieve the task mentioned in 5th point that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario you can use deeplink to call to invoke audio only or audio-video calls to a single user or a group of users, by specifying the call type, as audio or av, and the participants.

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>&withvideo=true
```

Please go through [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-an-audio-or-audio-video-call) for more info.

Comment: @svw1105 Please let know does that help clarify.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your suggestion. But when I am using below link it gives me an error like "There's a problem with this link"

API which I am using:

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=abc@domain.com

Comment: @svw1105 - when I click on the above URL I am getting prompt message in teams to call .https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj9ar.png

Comment: It means there might be some issue with our company domain. Because I am using my company's email there and I was getting an error.